# Whats wrong with my php to sql?

Tags: php, sql

```html
<?php
phpinfo
php $connect = mysql_connect(“localhost:3306”, “thebigsh_formdata”, “GaryJones123”); 
if (!connect) { die('Connection Failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
{ mysql_select_db(“database_name”, $connect);

$user_info = “INSERT INTO table_name (username, email) VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[email]')”; 
if (!mysql_query($user_info, $connect)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 } echo “Your information was added to the database.”; mysql_close($connect); 
 
 header('Location: http://thebigsheep.x10.bz/page2.html');
 ?>
```

I'm trying to link my website to sql database on x10 hosting. however it's not working?

Does anyone know why?

this is my php code i'm using

Comment: I seem to have forgotten my magic crystal ball at home. Does anybody have one that I can borrow? But seriously now, you need to post more info.

Comment: <?php
phpinfo
php $connect = mysql_connect(“localhost:3306”, “thebigsh_formdata”, “GaryJones123”); 
if (!connect) { die('Connection Failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
{ mysql_select_db(“database_name”, $connect);

$user_info = “INSERT INTO table_name (username, email) VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[email]')”; 
if (!mysql_query($user_info, $connect)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 } echo “Your information was added to the database.”; mysql_close($connect); 
 
 header('Location: http://thebigsheep.x10.bz/page2.html');
 ?>

Comment: What your code?

Comment: tag the correct tag

Comment: the code is shown above

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqi_*

Comment: www.thebigsheep.x10.bz

Comment: `mysql_connect(“localhost:3306”, “thebigsh_formdata”, “GaryJones123”)` for production? if yes, please remove it

Comment: @Andrew: google it :p

Comment: what is it? `if (!connect)` ?????????, 2- i hope you are using correct quotes not `“`, 3 - mysql_* is deprecated use, mysqli_* or PDO, 4 - your code is open for SQL injection, use prepared statements.

Comment: @G.Jones how do you know it fail ? What is the error reported ? Is it one of your `Die` statement ? You have your success message but nothing in the database ?

Comment: Take your time to write error messages and any specific details about your configuration that might be important for solving this issue. After that it might be a good idea to check if you have syntax errors `<?php
phpinfo
php $connect = ...` this does not seem valid. `phpinfo php` should be removed.

Comment: i got the code from another site but i dont understand why i cant not make it work. Im new to php so i dont really know much about it

Comment: first of all correct this, `if (!connect)`

Comment: can someone rewrite the code for me/

Comment: In that case you might want to read some tutorials or post a job on some of the freelance websites :D
This is not the place to ask for someone to write your code. It is a place where you can find help about specific problems.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: You are asking from people to write code for you. This is the place where you can get help solving problems, not writing code. My recommendation is to at least read tutorial which will take you not more then couple of hours, and you might understand what is the problem. First of all `phpinfo
php` which is on the begining of your code is not valid. it will give you syntax error. `connect` is not a valid variable name in PHP, so `(!connect)` is not valid part of code...Try removing those, and you might get some more useful error messages. Also, try adding error messages you get to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_* is deprecated so try to use mysqli_* or PDO

[refer the quickstart for connection creation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

> Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

```
        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "thebigsh_formdata"; //username

        $password = "GaryJones123"; //password

        $mysql_database = "database_name"; //database name

    //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

       mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

     $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (username, email) VALUES (?,?)");

                    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_POST[username],$_POST[email]);

                //  The argument may be one of four types:

                //  i - integer
                //  d - double
                //  s - string
                //  b - BLOB
                    //change it by respectively 

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $row_count= $stmt->affected_rows;
                    $stmt->close();
                     $conn->close();
```

Comment: it comes up with this error now? 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'thebigsh_formdat'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/thebigsh/public_html/database.php on line 24
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'thebigsh_formdat'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: On myphpadmin how do you find out the username and password?

Comment: SELECT * FROM mysql.user;

Comment: or in your phpmyadmin there is one schema like mysql expand that schema there is table name like "user" you can find there

Comment: it works but gets as far as the opps error statement

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'xo6.x10hosting.com' (using password: YES) in /home/thebigsh/public_html/database.php on line 24
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'admin'@'xo6.x10hosting.com' (using password: YES) i have this error now but it was working earlier

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/thebigsh/public_html/database.php on line 30

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_POST[username],$_POST[email]); it dosent like this line

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_POST['username'],$_POST['email']); try this @G.Jones